# How to make filters in Vue.js based on element list?

Tags: html, vue.js, filter, vue-component

## Introdution

Hi, I'm working on private project *"Avatar databse"* in Vue.js framework. App shows them based on `data()` elements:

```js
data() {
  return {
    avatars: [
        {
            name: "Butterfly Blue",
            tags: [
                "animal",
                "butterfly",
                "blue"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Butterfly Green",
            tags: [
                "animal",
                "butterfly",
                "green"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Deer Shining",
            tags: [
                "animal",
                "deer"
            ]
        },
```

## What I want

I would like to make search engine based on tags. Most of help pages are about previous Vue versions or search is based on name - one element. I want to search in tag **list** not single **name** string.

Without search engine, every avatar renders correctly

## Current component code

#### `template:`

```html
<div class="row">
    <div v-for="image in avatars" :key="filteredData" class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 my-2">
            <img v-bind:src="imgSource(image.name)" v-bind:alt="image.name" class="img-fluid" :class="avatarClass" />
            <a :href="imgSource(image.name)" :class="downloadClass"><span class="icon-download-alt"></span></a>
            <p class="h5 text-center py-1">{{ image.name }}</p>
            <p v-for="tag in image.tags" v-bind:key="tag" :class="tagClass">{{ tag }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### `computed()`

```js
avatarClass() {
        return 'avatar';
    },
    tagClass() {
        return 'tag';
    },
    downloadClass() {
        return 'download';
    },
    filteredData() {
        if (this.search == '') {
            return this.avatars;
        } else {
            return this.avatars.filter(obj => {
                return obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        };
    },
```

Of course filterind related thigs doesn't work. And there's my question...

### How to make working, tag list based, search engine?

(Based on my project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's small changes to the search that has been done. I've made a codesandbox where it's working:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-napier-3jk52

```
filteredData() {
  if (this.search == "") {
    return this.avatars;
  } else {
    return this.avatars.filter(obj => {
      return obj.tags.indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
  }
}
```

It's pretty simple. There's a search `data` variable, where you can put in the tag you want to search for. Right now it only searched for the whole tag, and has to match a tag fully, but this can be changed if you want people to be able to search for "anim", and then the `avatars` with the "animal" tag should be shown.

Comment: Thanks, it's working but as you said, only whole tag (and only one) is being searched. How to add option to search for multiple tags and "anim" will find "animal" tag?

Comment: Should it then be combined as the avatar HAVE to have both tags, or just one of them?

Comment: Both of them I think would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You enter butterfly in your search field and only Butterfly Blue and Butterlfy Green should appear?

Instead of

```
return this.avatars.filter(obj => {
                return obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
```

try this:

```
return this.avatars.filter(avatar => avatar.tags.includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
```